# Removing parts from HTML page in UIWebVIew

Tags: html, objective-c, uiwebview, nsstring

I'm trying to remove text from html page, and I'm using this code:

```
NSRange *r;
while ((r = [commentsOnly rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound) {
        commentsOnly = [commentsOnly stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"clearing");
    }
```

It removes html tags perfect, but how can I remove only one tag? For example, `title` or `p`. I don't want to remove only my tag. I want to remove start tag (`<p>`), info between two tags and close tag (`<\p>`).

Comment: The start tag + content + end tag is collectively known as the *element*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, may be this will help you:

```
NSString *string = @"</body>", *htmlString = @"ddsfsdf_<body>_sdfsfd_<body>ffff</body></body>";
NSRange range = [htmlString rangeOfString:string];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    range.length += range.location;
    range.location = 0;

    string = @"<body>";
    NSRange rangeOpen = [htmlString rangeOfString:string options:NSBackwardsSearch range:range];
    if (rangeOpen.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        range.length -= rangeOpen.location;
        range.location = rangeOpen.location;
        htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"%@", htmlString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to execute JavaScript within the `UIWebView` to do this.  This is much less work and is also much more reliable, as it will use WebKit's HTML parser instead of naïve string replacement.

Comment: He want to remove tags.. How 'stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString' can help here?

Comment: When the `UIWebView` displays the page, it parses it into a DOM.  Any JavaScript you execute can access the DOM to change it at will.